# Difference between , and ; on an instruction block

Tags: javascript, operators

I have a simple question. Imagine I have the following code:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", uri, !0), 
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"), 
xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

These are comma separated instructions.
What is the biggest difference between using `;` instead of `,`? Is it just to make sure all instructions are ran even if one of them gives an error or something?

Comment: as far as I know "," separate arguments and ";" ends the line, except for "for loop". Note that creating for example ajax call you are using "," inside the brackets.

Comment: yes, it works. I just want to know the difference. `,` isn't only a argument separator, it is also an operator. (like && and ||, but it evaluates both conditions all the time I think)

Comment: It’s the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), `,` is not only used for arguments, the things in the `for` loop are _not arguments_.

Comment: When you're not using the result of each expression for something, there's no practical difference. Expressions grouped by the comma operator will have the result of the last expression

Comment: This looks very much like the output of a minifier (especially the `!0`). Don't try to learn anything about style from this code.

Comment: it was minified. I am trying to analyse some code.